# Database first with Identity in .NET Core and Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I would like to use a Database First approach to managing my database with EF Core, and not just for the initial database creation. I'm using this command to generate my entity models and mapping code:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models/Entities -f
```

Now this works fine. I'm just struggling with identity integration. Currently I have two separate contexts, the one generated by the scaffolding command and an identity context that looks like this:

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {
    public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityContext> options)
        : base(options) {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Both contexts read from the same database and are registered like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Is it reasonable to have two separate contexts? Will it cause future problems as I start creating relationships between users and other models? I couldn't find anything in the docs regarding continued use of `db-scaffold` to generate my entity models and mappings.

Let me know if I can clarify anything.

---

**ORIGINAL CONTEXT**

Okay so clearly my original question wasn't any good.

I'd just like some clarification on if my Database First workflow with .NET Core and Entity Framework is the right way. I've read all the articles I can find about using Database First, which all seem to end with: "now you have scaffolded your database so can start using Code First migrations". I want to continue writing my SQL and just keep mapping it to entities.

To manage and update my application I'm using the excellent [DbUp](https://dbup.github.io/) project. So I write my scripts, apply them to the database

This appears to be working fine so far. My only problem is integrating identity nicely. Currently I just have two contexts, my application one and an identity one. My application one has also mapped all the identity tables. It is working fine but I'm not sure what will happen going forward as I start linking tables to the user... I believe I did make it work with one context but I had to modify the generated application context each time, removing all the Identity mappings and inheriting from IdentityDbContext (to generate the identity mappings). I could change the schema of the identity tables/my tables and just generate the mappings for my tables, excluding the identity tables. Then I will probably need to manually write mapping properties on ApplicationUser, is that correct?

Basically, I'm not really feeling like Database First is a first class citizen in .NET anymore. Am I just missing something obvious to have this kind of just "work" without modifying generated code? Or am I overthinking this and just need to get on with it?

Apologies for the rambling, one of those days I guess.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question but why use a single database for "identity" and application data. Seems you'd want to manage them separately.

Comment: I think a single database for identity and my application data makes sense, since while Identity is sort of .NET's thing, I would view users as part of my "application data"

Comment: It is an interesting question, but you must be aware that it doesn't fit SO format. You're getting lots of close votes. Can you make this a bit more well-constructed?  Maybe layout a more specific challenge, given the nature of the problem you're raising. I like to golf questions like this into a more constructivist form, but I don't have the bandwith now and I don't want to see an interesting question closed.

Comment: @NewAlexandria Thank you for the feedback, I do wish I received notifications on close votes so I could amend. I have edited the question and well, actually made a question out of it

Comment: *I'm not really feeling like Database First is a first class citizen in .NET anymore* That's correct. EF-core doesn't even support it any more. The code-first from database model generators (scaffolding) were made to give you a quick start into a code-first model, which you're supposed to amend manually as the application develops, with or without migrations.